# Is there some way can add label in legend in plot by one step?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

My legend now shows,
[image]

I want to add my label in legend,  from 0 to 7, but I don't want to add a for-loop in my code and correct each label step by step, my code like that,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Clusters by OPTICS in 2D space after PCA')
ax.set_xlabel('First Component')
ax.set_ylabel('Second Component')
points = ax.scatter(
    pca_2_spec[:,0], 
    pca_2_spec[:,1],
    s = 7,
    marker='o',
    c = pred_pca_2_spec,
    cmap= 'rainbow')
ax.legend(*points.legend_elements(), title = 'cluster')  
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pred_pca_2_spec` is some np.array with values `[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 35]` to change the values of these to be in the range 0-7, simply divide (each element) by 5.

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(54)
pca_2_spec = np.random.randint(-100, 300, (100, 2))
pred_pca_2_spec = np.random.choice([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35], 100)
```

Plotting Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Clusters by OPTICS in 2D space after PCA')
ax.set_xlabel('First Component')
ax.set_ylabel('Second Component')
points = ax.scatter(
    pca_2_spec[:, 0],
    pca_2_spec[:, 1],
    s=7,
    marker='o',
    c=pred_pca_2_spec / 5,  # Divide By 5
    cmap='rainbow')
ax.legend(*points.legend_elements(), title='cluster')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with new legend]